# Only one uv coordinates per vertex?

Tags: api, 3d, uv-mapping

A cube has 8 different vertexes. [image: texture] Mapping the faces to the texture is a problem because the 2d-texture has 14 different xy coordinates.

I like to know:

Is it common that one vertex has only one uv coordinate pair?

Comment: As a example, in OpenGL a "vertex" means a 3D point and all attributes associated with it, e.g. a texture coordinate. In higher-level APIs e.g. WPF / Unity they are usually decoupled.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog How are they decoupled?

Comment: Each "triangle" has separate vertex / UV indices and they are stored in separate buffers. The vertex data is then duplicated when passed to the underlying graphics API if necessary.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog "if necessary" sounds wague. To me, it looks like WPF/Unity must technically hold behind the scene a open cube/dice with additional 4 vertexes for one closing-side. The 4 vertices of the closing-side have the same position like the open side of the cube but different uv-coordinates.

Comment: By "if necessary" I meant depending on the API; OpenGL definitely requires duplication (not sure about Vulkan / D3D)

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25483486/1479630